# Tastypie get_or_create object

Tags: python, django, rest, tastypie

Is it possible to create a default object in tastypie? I'd like to create an object the first time it's retrieved through the REST api, so there's always a returned value. I could do this in `dehydrate`, but I also need to take into account `GET` parameters to create the object. What would be the best method to overload and how can I related objects (which the GET parameter refers to)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have found 'a' solution.

In `ModelResource`, I overload `obj_get_list`:

```
def obj_get_list(self, bundle, **kwargs):
    if bundle.request.method == 'GET':
        related_id = bundle.request.GET['entity']
        # create new object if it doesn't exist and populate with `related_id`
        # ...
    objects = ModelResource.obj_get_list(self, bundle, **kwargs)
    return objects
```

The url to call this would have a GET parameter `/url/to/resource?entity=1`.

Is there anything wrong with this solution? Can anyone foresee undesired side effects?

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to override the obj_get function.

```
def obj_get(self, bundle, **kwargs):
    pk = kwargs['pk']
    if pk.startswith('identifier'):
        pk = pk.replace("identifier/", "")
        instance, created = Model.objects.get_or_create(identifier=pk)
        kwargs['pk'] = str(instance.pk)

    return super().obj_get(bundle, **kwargs)
```

This allows a URL with the following format: `/url/to/resource/identifier/*some_identifier*`